# Docker Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I am trying to set up docker for my node js and typescript project and getting following error when trying to run `docker-compose run --service-ports web`

my composer file looks like below

```
services:
  web:
    image: node:alpine
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - .:/my-project
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: 'dev'
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    tty: true
```

Docker 
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That image doesn't have `bash` installed. Try with `entrypoint: ["sh"]`

Answer (score 2):

Alpine Linux uses [almquist shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell), so you have to call your script with **ash** instead of **bash**. As well check that your shell scripts are referring to correct unix shell e.g `#!/bin/ash`