# "Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed" error on Windows machine

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a simple Python image and then access the container interactively on Windows. The build process works, but running the container fails. This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.4
WORKDIR /app
```

Makefile:

```
IMAGE = scrapy_image
CONTAINER = scrapy_container
SHELL = bash

build:
    docker build \
    -t ${IMAGE} \
    .

shell:
    docker -D -l debug run \
    --name ${CONTAINER} \
    -v $(shell pwd):/app \
    -it \
    --rm \
    --entrypoint ${SHELL} \
    ${IMAGE}
```

Building the image is successful:

```
> Get-Date; make

Saturday, April 30, 2022 2:12:56 PM
-t scrapy_image \
.
[+] Building 2.1s (6/6) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 31B                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10.4                                                                                                1.9s 
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.10.4@sha256:edc8e6a550e4be7c340df18b252364554ea46a5ac14be4dcad711c285d25d1db                                          0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                          0.1s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => => writing image sha256:1dc5fb7c8cf8f7426690c9c8a87d585a192c645c6543f751090567e8c1a8deb5                                                                    0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/scrapy_image                                                                                                                 0.0s 

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
```

However, entering the container fails:

```
> Get-Date; make shell

Saturday, April 30, 2022 2:13:17 PM
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
Makefile:11: pipe: No such file or directory
docker -D -l debug run \
--name scrapy_container \
-v :/app \
-it \
--rm \
--entrypoint sh.exe \
scrapy_image
time="2022-04-30T14:13:20+01:00" level=debug msg="[hijack] End of stdout"
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "sh.exe": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
make: *** [Makefile:11: shell] Error 127

> docker logs scrapy_container
Error: No such container: scrapy_container
```

OS Information:

```
> (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption
Microsoft Windows 10 Home
> (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Version
10.0.19044
> (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture
64-bit
```

Logs in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Docker (OS time seems to be one hour ahead):

```
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.730050300Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> HEAD /_ping
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.783380500Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << HEAD /_ping (52.6401ms)
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.808175600Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> POST /session
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.810830200Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] (83308934) 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD C->S BackendAPI POST /usage: {"command":"imageBuildCliLinux","count":1}
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.812176200Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] Upgrading to raw stream
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.891072900Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: close C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.862682400Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (83308934) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S<-C 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD POST /usage
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.902268800Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [common/pkg/backend.(*backendClient).UpdateUsage(0xc0000aa4b0, {{0xc0005722e8, 0x12}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, 0x1})
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.902268800Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/backend/client.go:433 +0xc2
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.902268800Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [common/pkg/proxy.(*BackendAnalytics).sendCommand(0xc000216fc0, {0xc0c322, 0xa}, {0xc05b11, 0x3}, 0x1)
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.902268800Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/proxy/analytics.go:104 +0x10e
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.902268800Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [common/pkg/proxy.(*BackendAnalytics).trackRouteForHTTPMethod(0xd32cc8?, 0xc0003d6400, 0xad0120?, 0xc5cf80)
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.902268800Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/proxy/analytics.go:97 +0xf4
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.902268800Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] (83308934) 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD C<-S cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI POST /usage (96.0547ms): OK
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.902748600Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] usage imageBuildCliLinux + 1
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.902748600Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [common/pkg/proxy.(*BackendAnalytics).Middleware.func1({0xd32570, 0xc0003d2380}, 0xc0003d6400)
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.902748600Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/proxy/analytics.go:59 +0x8d
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.902748600Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> POST /v1.41/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&buildid=18c6a06363f9d788e186b6689fa22953d74c6048bde874caf449743650159e15&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&remote=client-session&rm=1&session=taua7onz1lmgimhju0rlvup9j&shmsize=0&t=scrapy_image&target=&ulimits=null&version=2
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.903287600Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0004a0000, {0xd32570, 0xc0003d2380}, 0xc000444100)
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.903325700Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:210 +0x1cf
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.903415200Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.895072000Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (83308934) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S<-C 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD bind: {"command":"imageBuildCliLinux","count":1}
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.903572000Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:00.897571700Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (83308934) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S->C 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD POST /usage (39.9973ms): OK
time="2022-04-30T13:13:03.137681484Z" level=info msg="http: HTTP proxy --> 3.228.155.36:443 Host:registry-1.docker.io:443 (Origin): CONNECT "
time="2022-04-30T13:13:03.401521444Z" level=info msg="http: HTTP proxy --> 3.228.155.36:443 Host:registry-1.docker.io:443 (Origin): Successfully connected to 3.228.155.36:443"
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.021064400Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << POST /v1.41/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&buildid=18c6a06363f9d788e186b6689fa22953d74c6048bde874caf449743650159e15&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&remote=client-session&rm=1&session=taua7onz1lmgimhju0rlvup9j&shmsize=0&t=scrapy_image&target=&ulimits=null&version=2 (3.1178175s)
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.032684000Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][E] Error closing raw stream to client: The pipe is being closed.
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.046067700Z][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] [common/pkg/proxy.(*passthrough).upgradeToRaw.func2()
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.046067700Z][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/proxy/passthrough.go:338 +0x167
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.046067700Z][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] [common/pkg/proxy.(*passthrough).upgradeToRaw
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.047097900Z][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/proxy/passthrough.go:331 +0x36d
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.046067700Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << POST /session (3.2383935s)
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.401487300Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> GET /system/df
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.418798900Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << GET /system/df (17.3116ms)
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.451725100Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> GET /images/sha256:1dc5fb7c8cf8f7426690c9c8a87d585a192c645c6543f751090567e8c1a8deb5/json
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.455889900Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << GET /images/sha256:1dc5fb7c8cf8f7426690c9c8a87d585a192c645c6543f751090567e8c1a8deb5/json (4.1648ms)
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.602813900Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> HEAD /_ping
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.608977200Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << HEAD /_ping (6.1633ms)
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.624046800Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.622960000Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (4b06bf6b) ec49d911-CLIAPI S<-C Go-http-client/1.1 POST /usage
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.625672100Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.625059100Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (4b06bf6b) ec49d911-CLIAPI S<-C Go-http-client/1.1 bind: {"command":"build","context":"moby","source":"cli-docker;buildkit","status":"success"}
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.626274600Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:04.626274600Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (4b06bf6b) ec49d911-CLIAPI S->C Go-http-client/1.1 POST /usage (5.788ms): OK
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.824400500Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> HEAD /_ping
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.827772800Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << HEAD /_ping (3.3723ms)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.844762600Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] (3ab22f7e) 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD C->S BackendAPI POST /usage: {"command":"containerCreateCliLinux","count":1}
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855042800Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: close C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.853665900Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (3ab22f7e) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S<-C 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD POST /usage
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855277000Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [common/pkg/backend.(*backendClient).UpdateUsage(0xc0000aa4b0, {{0xc0000905a0, 0x17}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, 0x1})
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855580400Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/backend/client.go:433 +0xc2
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855580400Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [common/pkg/proxy.(*BackendAnalytics).sendCommand(0xc000216fc0, {0xc103a7, 0xf}, {0xc05b11, 0x3}, 0x1)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855580400Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/proxy/analytics.go:104 +0x10e
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855763300Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [common/pkg/proxy.(*BackendAnalytics).trackRouteForHTTPMethod(0xd32cc8?, 0xc000444a00, 0xad0120?, 0xc5cf80)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855763300Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/proxy/analytics.go:97 +0xf4
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855763300Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [common/pkg/proxy.(*BackendAnalytics).Middleware.func1({0xd32570, 0xc0001f80e0}, 0xc000444a00)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855763300Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/proxy/analytics.go:59 +0x8d
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855763300Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0004a0000, {0xd32570, 0xc0001f80e0}, 0xc0003d6e00)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855763300Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:210 +0x1cf
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855763300Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] (3ab22f7e) 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD C<-S cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI POST /usage (11.5651ms): OK
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855763300Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] usage containerCreateCliLinux + 1
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855763300Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855763300Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> POST /v1.41/containers/create?name=scrapy_container
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855277000Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (3ab22f7e) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S<-C 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD bind: {"command":"containerCreateCliLinux","count":1}
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855763300Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.855277000Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (3ab22f7e) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S->C 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD POST /usage (2.6213ms): OK
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.920554400Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << POST /v1.41/containers/create?name=scrapy_container (64.7818ms)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.922977100Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> POST /v1.41/containers/a18f2e52bc0cc32122b49b655dc38feda867ceb829511d7e7aa5a2c117b14cbd/attach?stderr=1&stdin=1&stdout=1&stream=1
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.926034000Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] Upgrading to raw stream
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.927036600Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> GET /system/df
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.928534500Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> POST /v1.41/containers/a18f2e52bc0cc32122b49b655dc38feda867ceb829511d7e7aa5a2c117b14cbd/wait?condition=removed
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.933635200Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << GET /system/df (7.1018ms)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.933898500Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] (e137a516) 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD C->S BackendAPI POST /usage: {"command":"containerStartCliLinux","count":1}
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.938399800Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: close C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.936931000Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (e137a516) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S<-C 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD POST /usage
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.938399800Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [common/pkg/backend.(*backendClient).UpdateUsage(0xc0000aa4b0, {{0xc0005725a0, 0x16}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, 0x1})
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.938900300Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/backend/client.go:433 +0xc2
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.938900300Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [common/pkg/proxy.(*BackendAnalytics).sendCommand(0xc000216fc0, {0xc0f57a, 0xe}, {0xc05b11, 0x3}, 0x1)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.938900300Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/proxy/analytics.go:104 +0x10e
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.939170400Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [common/pkg/proxy.(*BackendAnalytics).trackRouteForHTTPMethod(0xd32cc8?, 0xc0003d7900, 0xad0120?, 0xc5cf80)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.939170400Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/proxy/analytics.go:97 +0xf4
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.939170400Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [common/pkg/proxy.(*BackendAnalytics).Middleware.func1({0xd32570, 0xc0003d29a0}, 0xc0003d7900)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.939170400Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/proxy/analytics.go:59 +0x8d
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.939170400Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0004a0000, {0xd32570, 0xc0003d29a0}, 0xc0003d7700)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.939170400Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] [ vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:210 +0x1cf
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.939431800Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.938307200Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (e137a516) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S<-C 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD bind: {"command":"containerStartCliLinux","count":1}
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.939431800Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.938399800Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (e137a516) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S->C 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD POST /usage (1.9933ms): OK
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.939431800Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] (e137a516) 28a5bb0e-ProxyCMD C<-S cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI POST /usage (5.5333ms): OK
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.939807900Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] usage containerStartCliLinux + 1
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.939955000Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> POST /v1.41/containers/a18f2e52bc0cc32122b49b655dc38feda867ceb829511d7e7aa5a2c117b14cbd/start
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.950978700Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> GET /images/sha256:1dc5fb7c8cf8f7426690c9c8a87d585a192c645c6543f751090567e8c1a8deb5/json
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.953943500Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] noopApprover.Approve([])
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.953943500Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] vpnkitApprover.Approve([])
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.955064700Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << GET /images/sha256:1dc5fb7c8cf8f7426690c9c8a87d585a192c645c6543f751090567e8c1a8deb5/json (4.086ms)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.957553100Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.957553100Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (d4233ac2) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S<-C Go-http-client/1.1 GET /forwards/list
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.971553200Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.971553200Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (d4233ac2) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S->C Go-http-client/1.1 GET /forwards/list (13.5015ms): []
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.972554100Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] vpnkitExposer.Add(approver-7108200055871598911, approver-7108200055871598911, [])
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.973053000Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] vpnkitExposer.Remove(approver-7108200055871598911)
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.973053000Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.973053000Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (cdcafe4a) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S<-C Go-http-client/1.1 GET /forwards/list
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.974052400Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.974052400Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (cdcafe4a) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S->C Go-http-client/1.1 GET /forwards/list (999.4Âµs): []
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.975052800Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] noopSharer.Add(a18f2e52bc0cc32122b49b655dc38feda867ceb829511d7e7aa5a2c117b14cbd, /scrapy_container, [])
[2022-04-30T13:13:17.985701700Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> GET /containers/a18f2e52bc0cc32122b49b655dc38feda867ceb829511d7e7aa5a2c117b14cbd/json
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.477346100Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.476857800Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (4594bbf7) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S<-C Go-http-client/1.1 GET /forwards/list
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.478504700Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] noopSharer.Remove(a18f2e52bc0cc32122b49b655dc38feda867ceb829511d7e7aa5a2c117b14cbd)
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.478852700Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << POST /v1.41/containers/a18f2e52bc0cc32122b49b655dc38feda867ceb829511d7e7aa5a2c117b14cbd/start (2.5388977s)
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.481304200Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << POST /v1.41/containers/a18f2e52bc0cc32122b49b655dc38feda867ceb829511d7e7aa5a2c117b14cbd/wait?condition=removed (2.5531728s)
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.482194100Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.482118900Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (4594bbf7) cb6bcf3b-BackendAPI S->C Go-http-client/1.1 GET /forwards/list (5.5402ms): []
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.484186800Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << GET /containers/a18f2e52bc0cc32122b49b655dc38feda867ceb829511d7e7aa5a2c117b14cbd/json (2.4984851s)
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.488540600Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << POST /v1.41/containers/a18f2e52bc0cc32122b49b655dc38feda867ceb829511d7e7aa5a2c117b14cbd/attach?stderr=1&stdin=1&stdout=1&stream=1 (2.5659652s)
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.499593500Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> GET /containers/a18f2e52bc0cc32122b49b655dc38feda867ceb829511d7e7aa5a2c117b14cbd/json
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.503709800Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << GET /containers/a18f2e52bc0cc32122b49b655dc38feda867ceb829511d7e7aa5a2c117b14cbd/json (4.1163ms)
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.558296000Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.556139800Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (26387769) ec49d911-CLIAPI S<-C Go-http-client/1.1 POST /usage
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.559087300Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.558579100Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (26387769) ec49d911-CLIAPI S<-C Go-http-client/1.1 bind: {"command":"run","context":"moby","source":"cli","status":"failure"}
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.560590000Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: write C:\Users\zirom\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.560124800Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (26387769) ec49d911-CLIAPI S->C Go-http-client/1.1 POST /usage (6.0363ms): OK
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.653582200Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> GET /system/df
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.664011600Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << GET /system/df (9.9331ms)
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.667219800Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> GET /images/sha256:1dc5fb7c8cf8f7426690c9c8a87d585a192c645c6543f751090567e8c1a8deb5/json
[2022-04-30T13:13:20.675511300Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy << GET /images/sha256:1dc5fb7c8cf8f7426690c9c8a87d585a192c645c6543f751090567e8c1a8deb5/json (8.2915ms)
time="2022-04-30T13:14:00.681310415Z" level=error msg="vmnet: Vmnet.Server.listen callback caught (Invalid_argument
[2022-04-30T13:14:00.681310800Z][VpnKit            ][Info   ]   "Cstruct.blit src=[9653,70](65536) dst=[0,14](14) dst-off=0 len=70")"
```

I tried changing the variable `SHELL` to "/bin/sh" and "/bin/bash", but it doesn't work. I also found a similar issue [here](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/246), but proposed solutions didn't work for me. Am I making a mistake somewhere?
I also found related questions here, but the proposed solutions didn't work:

- [Docker Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53530168/docker-error-response-from-daemon-oci-runtime-create-failed)

Comment: Hi, I personally wouldn't have included the `python` tag, as the question doesn't involve any issues with python code :)

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux containers?

Comment: Your volume mapping doesn't look like it works. `-v $(shell pwd):/app` ends up becoming `-v :/app`. To get it to work, I would suggest ditching some of the complexity you have and type the `docker run` commands manually. Then, when it works, add the complexity back.

Comment: Looks like you are using PowerShell, are you sure bash is even available? I don't PowerShell very well. But the equivalent of `pwd` is `Get-Location` maybe you should give it a try.

Comment: @HansKilian Docker daemon is running on Windows, the image is built on top of a Linux distribution. When passing `-v C:\Users\zirom\Documents\Projects\scrapy:/app` argument to `docker run` directly it is still the same error. Same with `-v "C:\Users\zirom\Documents\Projects\scrapy":/app`, `-v "C:\\Users\\zirom\\Documents\\Projects\\scrapy":/app` or `-v C:\\Users\\zirom\\Documents\\Projects\\scrapy:/app`. It is also the same error if I omit the `-v` option entirely.

Comment: @JulienB. Error remains the same with `Get-Location`, see also my previous comment - even passing the string directly doesn't change the error.

Comment: What if you wrap both your local path and your target in double quotes? `-v "c:\...:/app"`

Comment: @JulienB. still the same error if `-v "C:\Users\zirom\Documents\Projects\scrapy:/app"` or `-v "C:\Users\zirom\Documents\Projects\scrapy":"/app"` is passed. In case you wonder: file was also saved before running again.